# Change the dropdown selection of a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

In wordpress and I'm trying to use javascript/jquery to change the dropdown selection of a plugin when another plugin's map button is selected.

The map plugin states in the api that you can access the click on maps with this

```
$.imageMapProEventOpenedTooltip = function(imageMapName, shapeID) {}
```

I believe

```
$.imageMapProEventClickedShape = function(blackriver, oval-5197) {
```

would be what I want.

Here's the code for the plugin that is displaying the dropdown.

```
  <div id="DOPSelect-DOPBSPCalendar-form-field2_8" class="DOPSelect dopselect-single  "> 
    <input type="hidden" id="DOPBSPCalendar-form-field2_8" name="DOPBSPCalendar-form-field2_8" value="1">
     <div class="dopselect-select">
<div class="dopselect-selection">A</div>
     <div class="dopselect-icon">▾</div>
     </div> 
    <ul style="display: none;">
     <li id="DOPSelect-DOPBSPCalendar-form-field2_8-1" title="A" class="dopselect-selected">A</li>
     <li id="DOPSelect-DOPBSPCalendar-form-field2_8-2" title="B" class="">B</li>
     <li id="DOPSelect-DOPBSPCalendar-form-field2_8-3" title="C" class="">C</li>
     <li id="DOPSelect-DOPBSPCalendar-form-field2_8-4" title="D" class="">D</li> 
     <li id="DOPSelect-DOPBSPCalendar-form-field2_8-5" title="E" class="">E</li>
     <li id="DOPSelect-DOPBSPCalendar-form-field2_8-6" title="F" class="">F</li>
     <li id="DOPSelect-DOPBSPCalendar-form-field2_8-7" title="G" class="">G</li> 
     <li id="DOPSelect-DOPBSPCalendar-form-field2_8-8" title="H" class="">H</li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried throwing stuff together with what little I know (basically nothing) about javascript.

```
 $.imageMapProEventClickedShape = function(blackriver, oval-5197) {
  $('#DOPSelect-DOPBSPCalendar-form-field2_8-2').addClass("dopselect-selected");
  $('.dopselect-selection').text("B");
 }
```

I figured I needed to add the class since it adds it when they are selected but I didn't know what else to do so I just tried to change the text to see if I could change it.

When I tried to add it I get "Unexpected token" at the end of the first line.

```
$.imageMapProEventClickedShape = function(blackriver, oval-5197) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function declaration `function(blackriver, oval-5197) { ... }` is not valid becuase of `oval-5197`. The javascript interpreter cant bind the value you pass to the function paramater becuase of the `-`. The solution depends on your intention.

If you want to augment the paramater that is passed in by subtracting 5197 the simply move that operation into the function body:

```
$.imageMapProEventClickedShape = function(blackriver, oval) {
    oval = oval - 5197;
    ...
}
```

If your intention was to name the variable with a minus sign then simply change it to underscore or camal case:

```
$.imageMapProEventClickedShape = function(blackriver, oval_5197) { ... }
```

or

```
$.imageMapProEventClickedShape = function(blackriver, oval5197) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I needed to name it oval_5197 or oval5197 because the shape id is oval-5197 not a subtraction.